# Inexplicible echo function formatting

Tags: php

I have a program that runs calculation for shortest routes of two suppliers in a clients warehouse:

```
$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$tcase = fgets($_fp);

for ($a0 = 0; $a0 < $tcase; $a0++)
{            
    $count = fgets($_fp);
    $array = explode(' ', fgets($_fp));
    $max_ending_here = 0;
    $max_so_far = 0;
    $all_positives = 0;

    for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++)
    {

        $x = $array[$i];
        $max_ending_here = max(0, $max_ending_here + $x);
        $max_so_far = max($max_so_far, $max_ending_here);


        if ($array[$i] >= 0) {
            $all_positives = $all_positives + $array[$i];
        }
    }

    if ($max_so_far > 0) {
        echo $max_so_far . ' ' . $all_positives . "\n";
    } else {
        echo $array[0] . ' ' . $array[0] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

When I place in standard input I get an unexpected formatting mistake on the output where two of the negative numbers don't stay on the same line. This occurs at the final `else {echo $array[0] . ' ' . $array[0] . "\n";}`. I've tried literally everything I can think of and I still get something that looks like:

```
1 1
-1 -1
1 1
6 6
-10
 -10

5 6
```

The problem being the two -10s, is there some kind of unheard of line limiter that needs to be increased?

Comment: without info on your css it will be hard to identify what the issue is... provided you're displaying the results in html, of course...

Comment: It's not this is CLI output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a newline character (`\n`) at the end of your string in `$array[0]`.

When `-10` should be printed, there is `-10\n` in `$array[0]`.

Please try replacing

```
$array = explode(' ', fgets($_fp));
```

with

```
$array = explode(' ', fgets($_fp));
$array = array_map('trim', $array);
```

to remove spaces, linebreaks etc. in your string.

Answer (score 1):

Unless EOF is reached fgets returns a string including a newline character. I suspect that is your problem as you never cast it to integer, nor strip the newline. Either of the following should fix that for you:

1. Change `$array[0] . ' ' . $array[0] . "\n"`
   to `((int) $array[0]) . ' ' . $array[0] . "\n"`
2. Change `$array = explode(' ', fgets($_fp));`
   to `$array = explode(' ', trim(fgets($_fp)));`